# C# Bungie API ExpandoObject issue

Tags: c#, json, api, discord

I seem to be facing some issue when trying to read the JSON response from Bungie API, the below method usually works but for some reason i am now getting error message.

Function Code

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetMemberID(string MembersName)
    {
        List<string> MembershipID = new List<string>();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(StaticObjects.bungieBasePath + $@"/User/SearchUsers/?q={MembersName}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                dynamic content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result;
                foreach (dynamic user in content.Response.results)
                {
                    MembershipID.Add(user.membershipId);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The member could not be found.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("An error occurred retrieving the members information.");
        }

        return MembershipID;
    }
```

Command Code

```
[Command("invite")]
    [RequireContext(ContextType.Guild, ErrorMessage = "This command is specific to a particular server so you must send it from a channel within that server")]
    public async Task JoinDateAsync([Remainder]string MemberName)
    {
        using (Context.Channel.EnterTypingState())


            if (!Context.IsPrivate) await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();

        if (StaticObjects.CheckUserIsAdmin(Context))

        {
            List<string> MembershipID = await StaticObjects._bungie.GetMemberID(MemberName);

        }
    }
```

The first part all works fine and i can see the JSON Response in the console however when i try to pull out the "membershipId" i then get an error in the console and cannot figure out where i'm going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted my issue, the `JSON` response was slightly different. After i removed one word it now works.

From

```
foreach (dynamic user in content.Response.results)
```

To

```
foreach (dynamic user in content.Response)
```